# HttpListener returns 400 Bad Request for hosts with trailing dot

Tags: .net, httplistener

It looks like the HttpListener class returns status 400 "Bad Request" if the Host header contains host name with a trailing dot.

Code (based on [HttpListener example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
using System.Text;
using System.Net;

namespace HttpListenerTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleListenerExample(new []{"http://*:8081/"});
        }

        public static void SimpleListenerExample(string[] prefixes)
        {
            var listener = new HttpListener();
            foreach (var s in prefixes)
                listener.Prefixes.Add(s);
            listener.Start();
            while (true)
            {
                var context = listener.GetContext();
                var response = context.Response;
                var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>");
                response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
                var output = response.OutputStream;
                output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                output.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then run curl:

```
Error 400:
c:\...> curl -v --header "Host: localhost.local." http://localhost.:17320/
c:\...> curl -v --header "Host: localhost." http://localhost.:17320/

OK 200:
c:\...> curl -v --header "Host: localhost.local" http://localhost.:17320/
c:\...> curl -v --header "Host: localhost" http://localhost.:17320/
```

Any way to configure HttpListener in a way that both "localhost" and "localhost." requests are served equally well?